# Is too much nesting killing Eclipse code completion (in lambda functions)?

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda

I am having this piece of code from a current project:

```
Map<Long, List<ShopOfferDTO>> collect = this.ctx.select(
        SHOP_OFFER.ID,
        SHOP_OFFER.SHOP_ID,
        SHOP_OFFER.SHOP_TIMES_TYPE_ID,
        asTable.field(SHOP_OFFER_TIME_PERIOD.VALID_FOR_DAYS_BITMASK),
        asTable.field(SHOP_OFFER_TIME_PERIOD.PRICE)
        )
        .from(SHOP_OFFER)
        .join(asTable)
        .on(asTable.field(SHOP_OFFER_TIME_PERIOD.SHOP_OFFER_ID).eq(SHOP_OFFER.ID)
                .and(SHOP_OFFER.SHOP_TIMES_TYPE_ID.eq(offerType)))
        .fetchInto(ShopOfferDTO.class).stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        (ShopOfferDTO shopOfferDto) -> {

                            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                                shopOfferDto. // No code completion
                            }

                            // Again: guessing/knowledge required
                            return shopOfferDto.getShopId();
                        },
                        Collectors.mapping(
                                (shopOfferDto) -> shopOfferDto,
                                Collectors.toList()
                                )
                        ));
```

Inside `Collectory.groupingBy(...)` I have no code completion. The types are getting inferred correctly but hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> after `.` does not show anything. Not even methods of `Object` like `toString()` etc.

I can only observe this here. In all other places code completion/suggestion is working flawlessly.

Is there anything I can do about this?

---

Eclipst Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)

Comment: In what version of Eclipse? This is Java source, right?

Comment: @nitind The version is Mars.1 Release (4.5.1), I added it to my question as well as the Java tag.

Comment: Have you retried it with the current release, Mars.2?

Comment: @nitind nope not yet actually. You think this would work?

Comment: I have no idea, but it seems like the very first thing to try.